# problems with swt layout on different screens

Tags: java, layout, swt

I am using eclipse and swt to develop a UI for my application.  can some one tell me the best layout strategy to follow for makeing the ui look well inline on both wide and square screens?  Right now it looks good on wide screen but on square one the widgets in table are not getting aligned neetly.I have used form layout and have a table in a few screens along with other widgets.  The table columns have  static widths so on square screens they don't look good.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Have a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and try to find out a layout that suits as per your requirement.

Comment: Please post a picture of your design.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html). If your question persists, please post a screenshot and some code, so we can have a look at what you are talking about.

Comment: @Braj The question is about SWT, not Swing/AWT.